# How to use gets() in cpp

Tags: c++, gets, cstdio

These days I am learning strings and arrays in cpp. In my school they taught us to take a string as user input, one have to use gets() but it isn't working on any of the compilers I have.
I have already tried using cstdio library, still errors.
I know cin.getline() but it is a bit bigger word.

Comment: You don't use `gets()` anywhere.  It is not safe.  It is no longer a part of the C11 standard C library.  See [Why the `gets()` function is too dangerous to be used — ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Comment: Don't ise `gets()`, period. Use `fgets` instead, this is safe function. And if you are using C++, then use C++ methods , like `std::cin` from `iostream`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ohh!
I didn't know that
Thnx for ur help

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=fgets it's not that hard to look for a function in the internet.

Comment: documentation on most C library functions can be found with `man<name of function>` on the command prompt of a unix-like operating system or a websearch for `man<name of function>`. Another excellent place to look for information is at cppreference.com. If you find cppreference difficult to read, fall back to cplusplus.com, which is generally easier to read,but sometimes traded that readability for precision and is slightly wrong. If you suspect you've run across one of those slightly wrong cases, use what you learned from cplusplus.com  to take another crack at reading cppreference.

Comment: Apologies. In the above comment `man<name of function>` should read `man <name of function>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::cin.get();` is something they teach in beginner classes, hopefully this is the smaller word for getline you were hoping for! :)

In the future, use a program like Visual Studio which has IntelliSense and can list options for you - or just look at the documentation.

The best method would probably be something along these lines:

```
std::cout << "Input a string: ";
std::string strInput;
std::cin >> strInput;
std::cout << std::endl << "Your string: " << strInput << std::endl;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thnx @j. Doe
cin.get is perfect
Thnx for ur wishes

Answer (score 1):

```
cin.get()
```

is the thing you are looking for.  However, I recommend using cin, as that is sufficient to use `cin >>` .
This `cin>>` can also be used to input numbers, characters, strings etc.

```
 gets() and puts()
```

are commonly used in code golf, although they serve the same function as `cin>>` and `cout<<`.
I hope this post helps!

Answer (score -1):

SEE, 'cin' is used to basically  take any input of any data type. BUT. When u input a string using cin it makes an assumption that the string terminates after u enter space. 
So if u enter 'Hello world' It only reads 'Hello'. 
When u use gets() it also incorporates spaces into ur input. 
Syntax:
gets(stringName) ;
Don't  forget to include the header file

Comment: `cin` is an input stream and has little to do with how you read data from the stream. What is described in the above answer is the behaviour of the `>>` operator. The stream's `getline` method may be a better fit for `gets`, but when using C++ use `std::string` and ``std::getline` unless you are forced not to by some unfortunate circumstances.